# Is there a way for me to upload an image on tkinter without using PIL?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to upload a gif image from file in tkinter but I get an error message. I am new to using tkinter and I am aware to upload gif images we can use PhotoImage class.

I downloaded the image that I want to upload.

```
from tkinter import *      
root = Tk()      
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)      
canvas.pack()      
img = PhotoImage(file="compman.gif")      
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)      
mainloop()
```

This is the error I get 
couldn't open "compman.gif": no such file or directory

Comment: It means that the file is not found. Please describe your file/folder system and how you run the script.

Answer (score -1):

You should find have this file 'compman.gif' in this code file path.

[this is your situation now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoNFI.png)

[this is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5r57.png)

Comment: No, not in the code file path. As written, it needs to be in the current working directory, which might not be the same as where the code exists.